# Timer with Pygame

Tags: python, timer, pygame

I'm stuck in the development of my project in Python, with Pygame.

I'm trying to make an animation which will be start when I call the "explosion" method.
In fact, it have to create a timer, and depending of values, different images are going to be load, they constitute the animation of an explosion.

I searched a lot but I found only timer about fps or other things...

Please help me !

```
class Obus(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    #Initialisation 
    def __init__(self, angle, image):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self) 
        self.angle = angle
        self.image = pygame.image.load(image).convert_alpha()
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.stockRebonds = 1

    #Vérification du nombre de rebonds effectués 
    def rebond(self):
        if self.stockRebonds == 0:
            return False
        else:
            self.stockRebonds -= 1
            return True

    #Changement de direction 
    def rebondir(self, angle): 
        if self.angle == 'bas': 
            self.angle = 'haut'
        elif self.angle == 'haut':
            self.angle = 'bas'
        elif self.angle == 'droite':
            self.angle = 'gauche'
        elif self.angle == 'gauche':
            self.angle = 'droite'

    #Animation d'explosion 
    def explosion(self):
        refrExplosion = pygame.time.Clock()
        if refrExplosion < 100:
            self.image = pygame.image.load("explosion_1.png")
        elif refrExplosion > 100: 
            self.image = pygame.image.load("explosion_2.png") 

    #Déplacement de l'obus 
    def update(self):
        global obus_liste
        if self.angle == 'bas':
            x, y = 0, 6
            self.image = pygame.image.load("obus_bas.png").convert_alpha()
        elif self.angle == 'haut':
            x, y = 0, -6
            self.image = pygame.image.load("obus_haut.png").convert_alpha()
        elif self.angle == 'droite':
            x, y = 6, 0 
            self.image = pygame.image.load("obus_droite.png").convert_alpha()
        elif self.angle == 'gauche':
            x, y = -6, 0 
            self.image = pygame.image.load("obus_gauche.png").convert_alpha()
        else: return 

        #Test de déplacement à la nouvelle position 
        collision_obus_obstacles = self.rect.move(x,y).collidelist(obstacles)
        if collision_obus_obstacles == -1:
            self.rect.move_ip(x,y) 

        #Collision et rebond ?
        elif not collision_obus_obstacles == -1:
            if self.rebond():
                self.rebondir(self.angle)
            else:
                self.explosion()
```

Comment: What exactly are you asking? What I'm getting is you're going to need threads. Or you have the option of starting the explosion and then updating the explosion. Your creating of a time is doing nothing

Answer (score 0):

First of all I would have loaded all the images in the init part of Obus class.

```
self.image_bas = pygame.image.load("obus_bas.png").convert_alpha()
self.image_haut = pygame.image.load("obus_haut.png").convert_alpha()
```

etc...

Then, in update you could just do

```
self.image = self.image_bas
```

Or whatever image you need in the situation, instead of constantly loading the images, as it seems you are doing now.

Doing this you will also see that you can add the explosion images too, in the same way.

```
self.expl_image_1 = pygame.image load.....
```

and so on, depending on number of explosion pictures you will have.
I presume that it is Obus who explodes.

Then to your question:-)

Instead of calling self.explosion as you do in "#Collision et rebond ?"
I would just set a new bolean to true. 
And get the time when explosion started, like this:

```
 #Collision et rebond ?
 elif not collision_obus_obstacles == -1:
    if self.rebond():
        self.rebondir(self.angle)
    else:
        self.explosion = True
        if self.ticks_expl == 0:
            self.ticks_expl = pygame.time.get_ticks()
```

then in update I would test

```
if self.explosion == true:
    now = pygame.time.get_ticks()
    self.image = self.expl_image_1

    if now - self.ticks_expl > self.ticks_to_display_each_explosion_image:
        self.image = self.expl_image_2
    if now - self.ticks_expl > self.ticks_to_display_each_explosion_image *2
        self.image= self.expl_image_3

    etc...
```

depending on how many images and how long the explosion scene you want.
When you are happy with the explosion you set

```
self.explosion = False.
self.ticks_expl = 0
```